# Does NSUserDefaults always do IO when executed?

Tags: nsuserdefaults

NSUserDefaults is persistent right? If we close application it's still there. So it's IO.

Does that mean everytime we do

`– setObject:forKey:` we do IO?

Does iPhone will read and write to disk everytime we do

```m
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:trimmedSearchLocation forKey:SEARCHNEAR];
```

or that sort of thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> At runtime, you use an NSUserDefaults object to read the defaults that your application uses from a user’s defaults database. NSUserDefaults caches the information to avoid having to open the user’s defaults database each time you need a default value. The synchronize method, which is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, keeps the in-memory cache in sync with a user’s defaults database.

so only if `synchronize` invokes you have IO on your disk!

Answer (score 1):

The system syncs the settings periodically. You rarely have to sync them explicitly.